# Session not set when set session.cookie_secure = 1

Tags: php, session

When I add this in .htaccess

```
php_value session.cookie_secure 1
```

the `$_SESSION['online'] = session_id()` was changed every page refresh?

Comment: can you include a little more of your code?

Comment: <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['online']))
 $_SESSION['online'] = session_id();
?>

It works good. But when add php_value session.cookie_secure 1 to .htaccess, it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`session.cookie_secure`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure) specifies that the session cookie can only be sent over a secure connection, i.e. HTTPS:

> session.cookie_secure specifies whether cookies should only be sent
>   over secure connections.

That means, if you are not using HTTPS, your session won't work.